# How to deal with bugs which cause URL Truncation

Tags: html, magento, html-helper

I am a working on a website  for a leisure portal company in Germany. I am having trouble dealing with a truncated url. If you were to go to the web link http://www.regiondo.de/staedte/duesseldorf/lernen-unterricht-duesseldorf/musikkurse-duesseldorf , on the left side of the screen under KATEGORIEN, you would see          Gitarrenunterricht (1).

If you click on it, the user is redirected and gets a 404 page not found error, since the actual url to where the user is supposed to redirected is  http://www.regiondo.de/staedte/duesseldorf/lernen-unterricht-duesseldorf/musikkurse-duesseldorf/gitarrenunterricht-duesseldorf  ,  is truncated  and 'duesseldorf' at the end of the url truncates to just duessel

Now I have looked at the HTML  code for the webpage and it has the specific code:-

```
a href=/staedte/duesseldorf/lernen-unterricht-duesseldorf/musikkurse-duesseldorf/gitarrenunterricht-duessel>Gitarrenunterricht (1)
```

Now I understand that by changing duessel to duesseldorf I can rectify this issue but this url truncation inside the HTML is happening for many other urls as well(all of which were knowingly typed correctly). What are the possible problems or bugs from the backend which could cause such URL truncation problems. Since I am new to web development I would love to hear your suggestions and views. Thank you.

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer without knowledge of your backend. It has got nothing to do with either HTML or HTML5 though. We need way more information about your web application to help.

Comment: The website uses the Magento platform.

Comment: Are all the URL paths truncated to 100 characters or is it different for each of them?

Comment: No, the character length is not fixed its different for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento build set the products to not use the category name in the URLs. Then the problem goes away.

http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/catalog/

Then in Search Engine Optimisations section:

Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> No